# Can I change the interval at which formula is recalculated for longer? (like for every 6 months)

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, formula, formula-field, administration

I want to change a recalculation period of formula to 6 months.

How could I do this? Can I do this at all?

Could we schedule it somehow? With the use of flow/ code?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no. Formula fields are recalculated every time you view or query a record. That's just how formula fields act, and we can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

Formulas take up no storage space and are not stored as record data. Since they are not stored as record data, this is why using formulas in filters can cause "non-selective query" errors, as the entire database must be recalculated to see which values meet the criteria<sup>†</sup>. If you want to have something that can be periodically updated, you could use a normal editable field, and use a Process Builder/Flow to calculate a value derived from a formula, and then use a Scheduled Flow or Scheduled Apex to periodically update the data.

<sup>†</sup> *You can request a Custom Index for formulas as long as they are not time dependent (e.g. no use of TODAY() functions) and not cross-object references (e.g. Contact.Account.Name), though this is not the default behavior.*